# Generating images in UIView when touches the image in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app am having one UIView in that one UIScrollView in this some UIImageViews with images(form server) are there & loading dynamically. My requirement is when i touch on the image in the scrollview image has to generate in UIView exactly on the top of the UIScrollView images. For this i am using UITapGestureRecognizer. Image is generating in UIView but not exactly on the top of the images in scrollView.
Any one can help go suggest.

in view did load am having one static array for coordinates of generate image which i want to calculate dynamically

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    xCordArray = [[NSArray  alloc]initWithObjects:@"30",@"78",@"126",@"174",  @"222",@"270",@"318",@"366",@"34",@"82",@"130",@"179",@"226",@"274",@"322",@"369",@"38" ,@"88",@"136", @"183",@"248",@"278",@"316",@"375", nil];
   UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
   [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap]; 
   [self populateScrollView];  
   scrollView.delegate = self;
   NSMutableArray *getEffectsImageData = [ud objectForKey:@"getimageeffects"];
   int scrollViewWidth = [getEffectsImageData count]*48;
   [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollViewWidth, 40)];  
}
```

In the following singleTapGestureCaptured method am generating image with static xCordArray values. I want to generate this dynamically.

```
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{ 
    NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *getEffectsImageData = [ud objectForKey:@"getimageeffects"];
    TonifyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TonifyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication         sharedApplication].delegate;
    ImageToDrag *img = [[ImageToDrag alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<[getEffectsImageData count]; i++)
    {
         UIImageView *ImageView = [imageViewsArray objectAtIndex:i];
         NSString *sfxUrlFileName = [[getEffectsImageData objectAtIndex:i] lastPathComponent];
         NSLog(@"sfxUrlFileName: %@", sfxUrlFileName);
         NSData *imageData = [appDelegate    readSongDataFromDocsDirectory:sfxUrlFileName];
         UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
         CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:self.scrollView];
         int xc = [[xCordArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];// i want to calculate this xc dynamically.
         if(CGRectContainsPoint(ImageView.frame,location))
         {
             img = [img initWithImage:image];
             img.frame = CGRectMake(xc,240, 45, 42);
             img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
             [self.view addSubview:img];
             img.tag = i;
         }  
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code that you have implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to replace `img.frame = CGRectMake(xc,240, 45, 42);` with `img.frame = [self.scrollView convertRect:ImageView.frame toView:self.view];` and it "works". But there's a lot more strange in your code. Think about adding one gesture recognizer to each image view instead of one "global" gesture recognizer at the scroll view. By that you could get rid of the loop and the frame setting which is reason for your question gets less complicated also.

Comment: Actually we don't know how many images are there. They are coming from server dynamically.